# imagemagick: wrong color during conversion of png file

Tags: colors, centos, imagemagick, png, rgb

I have an [original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY0lW.png) image, and I want just to resize it, but during resizing, [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7HP8.png) image become more red. I have tried a lot of params, but no one works. Also strange is that on my local ubuntu everything is ok, problem occurs only on CentOs server;

This is what I tried:

```
convert fileForRedTest.png -background white -alpha remove fileForTest-result.png
convert fileForRedTest.png -colorspace RGB  fileForRedTest-result.png
convert fileForRedTest.png -define png:bit-depth=16 fileForRedTest-result.png
convert fileForRedTest.png -define png:bit-depth=16 -define png:color-type=6 fileForRedTest-result.png
convert fileForRedTest.png png32:fileForRedTest-result.png
```

Comment: Your local server probably has a different version of Imagemagick. If it is the default install it could be three or more years out of date and Imagemagick is under continuous development.

Comment: I updated version, but the problem remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was two reason:

1. Old version of lib (that's why I was getting different result)
2. This parameters: -define png:exclude-chunk=all -strip

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#strip), "`-strip`" is a shortcut for "`-define png:exclude-chunk=EXIF,iCCP,iTXt,sRGB,tEXt,zCCP,zTXt,date`", so probably very similar to your suggested "`-define png:exclude-chunk=all`". I don't know what specifying both does, but for me, "`-strip`" alone worked to correct the colour issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment. 
On Windows: IM 6.8.9 also caused to much red. Upgraded to the latest, 6.9.3 fixed the problem. I would take one more look at the binaries on the target machine.